# clang, implicit template instantiation first required inside a constructor declaration

Tags: c++, templates, clang

Here is a simple version of my problem:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Extractor
{
public:
    static const int& value;
};

class Bar
{
    
};

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {
        m_value = Extractor<Bar>::value;
    }
    
public:
    int m_value;
};

int gValue = 42;
template<> const int& Extractor<Bar>::value = gValue;

int main()
{
    Foo<Bar> test;
    std::cout << " Hello, world " << test.m_value << std::endl;
}
```

g++ gives no error and displays correctly.

clang return the following error message:

```
1184815205/source.cpp:30:39: error: explicit specialization of 'value' after instantiation
template<> const int& Extractor<Bar>::value = gValue;
                                      ^
1184815205/source.cpp:22:35: note: implicit instantiation first required here
        m_value = Extractor<Bar>::value;
```

The spec specify:

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is
> explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared
> before the first use of that specialization that would cause an
> implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in
> which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

**before the first use of that specialization**
I think that my snippet respect this rule cause the actual instantiation of the template appears in the `main()` function, the Foo constructor should not be compilled yet. Am I missing something ?

Moving the template specialization up would resolve the issue but I can't afford that.

Comment: No your first use should be before class Foo is declared.  See https://godbolt.org/z/YqEYKnj3x so that line 25 (in my godbolt link) can be compiled.
The wording "first use" can be a bit tricky.

Comment: You can also move the definition of `Foo::Foo()` down (after the template specialization).

Answer (score 5):

Since `Extractor<Bar>` is not dependent on `T`, it can either be instantiated to lookup `value` in the declaration or when it is actually instantiated. Clang is more eager, as it is allowed to be.

The easiest fix is to simply declare the specialization for `Extractor<Bar>::value` and define it later:

```cpp
class Bar
{
    
};

template<> const int& Extractor<Bar>::value;  // Declaration here

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {
        m_value = Extractor<Bar>::value;  // Will use the specialzation
    }
    
public:
    int m_value;
};

int gValue = 42;
template<> const int& Extractor<Bar>::value = gValue;  // Actual definition
```

Or fake a dependency on the template parameters:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename... Dependencies>
struct dependent_type_identity { using type = T; };
template<typename T, typename... Dependencies>
using dependent_type_identity_t = typename dependent_type_identity<T, Dependencies...>::type;


m_value = Extractor<dependent_type_identity_t<Bar, T>>::value;
// Or
m_value = dependent_type_identity_t<Extractor<Bar>, T>::value;
```

Comment: *'clang is more eager'* – in which way? Do you happen to mean GCC, as this one did compile when it (if I understand the matter right) shouldn't?

Comment: @Aconcagua More eager in that `Extractor<Bar>::value` is instantiated when the `Foo` template is defined (earlier, more eager template parsing) rather than when that template definition for `Foo<Bar>` is instantiated in `main` (more lazily). Both are acceptable behaviours. I believe this is ill-formed NDR, so gcc is not wrong in compiling this, but neither is clang in erroring.